# convert string to array of integer

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I would like to convert a string to a array of integer

```
 Dim yValues() As Integer = strTosplit.Split(New Char() {","}).Select(Function(n) Integer.Parse(n)).Sum()
```

the preceding code gives an error: value of type integer can not be converted to 1 dimensional integer.

Comment: Would you please provide a list of inputs to the code.

Comment: strTosplit() as string = {200, 700, 5000}

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of integers instead of the sum of the integers, you need ToArray instead of Sum.

```
Dim strTosplit As String = "1,2,3"
Dim yValues() As Integer = strTosplit.Split({","c}).Select(Function(n) Integer.Parse(n)).ToArray
```

Note that Integer.Parse will throw an exception if any of the elements cannot be parsed into integers.

Comment: I get an exception: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: I get no such exception using the code I posted. I see from your comment on the original post that you have declared strTosplit as an array of String.   You should probably declare it as an array of Integer `Dim strNoNeedToSplit As Integer = {200, 700, 5000}`.

Comment: Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT quantity from cargo"
        command = New MySqlCommand(cmdstring, connection)

        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        While reader.Read()
     
                      strQtyToSplit += reader("quantity") & " "
          
        End While
        MsgBox(strQtyToSplit)
       
        Dim yValues() As Integer = (strQtyToSplit.Split({" "c})).Select(Function(n) Integer.Parse(n)).ToArray
        Dim strVal As String = "10"

Comment: If you are reading numbers from your database, then either read them as numbers, or if you must read them as strings, convert each one to an integer when you read it. I would suggest adding the numbers to a List(Of Integer). If you really need an array, you can use the ToArray method to convert the List to an array when you have finished reading.